# 1996 Honda civic Ex cranks but won't start after replacing distributor and endcap on rocker arm

Tags: civic

I was replacing the distributor on my honda and the rocker arm endcap broke, so I went to a junkyard and got a replacement. I put that replacement on the rocker arm assembly and bolted up the new distributor, then it wouldn't start just crank. We brought the first piston to TDC then bolted the distributor on, not much difference. One day I went out and tried to start it with the gas to the floor, it started but sounded extremely rough and would only stay running if I revved it up if I took my foot off the gas it would stall. Any ideas?

Comment: Considering that you were working on the distributor, I'd start there.  My guess is that you have it installed incorrectly so that the spark timing is off.

Comment: Was the piston on a compression or exhaust stroke when you set it at TDC?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, I would say that you have likely installed the distributor with the rotor pointing at spark plug lead number 1 when the engine was on an exhaust stroke, rather than on a compression stroke.

If this is not correct, then you are maybe a few degrees out.